# Cast byte[,] to int[] in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to cast a `byte[,]` into an `int[]` by doing the following:

```cs
int[] tmp = items.Cast<int>().ToArray();
```

Where items is of type `byte[,]`.

Comment: Is the intention that each `byte` then occupies an entire `int` by itself, or were you thinking of e.g. combining each 4 adjacent bytes into a single `int`?

Comment: You would first need to flatten the 2-dimensional byte array and then cast each `byte` to an `int`

Comment: @phuzi the enumerator of an `byte[,]` yields the individual bytes, it's already flattened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `Cast<T>` to directly convert from bytes to ints (because the bytes get boxed and cannot be unboxed to `int`), so you have to use `Select`:

```
int[] tmp = items.OfType<byte>().Select(b => (int)b).ToArray();
```